# Error on IE 9 - 'SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This particular page works on Firefox and Chrome.
On IE9, I am getting this error: **SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation.**
I noticed this error message discussed in other posts as well but they deals with other problems.

Here is the code that throws the error. I am using trends charts (and highcharts for other tables) for my website.

```
<script>
jsio('import .js.trends');
new js.trends.Table({              // ERROR THROWN ON THIS LINE
target: 'trends_table',
type: 'credits',
noData: 'No credits yet!',
columns: [{
    title: 'Date',
    src: 'begin_date',
    format: 'date'
}, {
    title: 'Time',
    src: 'begin_date',
    format: 'time'
}, {
    title: 'Credits Earned',
    src: 'credits_earned',
    format: 'number'
}, {
    title: 'How Earned',
    src: 'activity',
    format: 'lookup',
    values: {
        0: 'ABC',
        1: 'DEF'
    }
}, {
    title: 'Credits Spent',
    src: 'credits_spent',
    format: 'number'
}]
}).refresh();
</script>
```

I am a little confused about the changes that I should make. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing quote at `values: {0: 'ABC` (at the end), and too much commas at the end (`1: 'DEF',`). If you fix these issues, does the problem disappear?

Comment: No, that was a typo in creating a simpler module. I took out a large message and put in ABC. Sorry about that. Correcting the mistake.

Comment: answer for this meta question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98269/inline-editing-problems + comment on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536452(v=vs.85).aspx , lead to me to think that you should not make `Table` in the way you are trying to create it with this unknown ugly framework.

Comment: Its hard to tell, most questions on this error here are about IE and tbody.

Comment: How do we know it's not an issue with the library you're using?  You should try reproducing this without any libraries.

Comment: What's the HTML? Is trends_table the target to place the chart? If so, what's the element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think IE has inconsistent support for the insertAdjacentHTML method, and  for elements like TR and TBODY , IE will throw an exception if the method is called on those methods. 
This error exists since IE6.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted Internet Explorer has had issues setting the contents of `<table>`, `<tr>`,`<td>` etc. via `.innerHTML`, `.insertAdjacentHTML` has several bugs up until IE10 running specifically in Standards Mode.

Bug report and workarounds: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/12/bug-210-no-innerhtml-support-on-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

If your element is a table, I believe it's one of those elements that are read-only with IE9.

Comment: This seems to be correct for me. I can't load data into a table but I can load it into a div. Only on IE9. Upvote this answer.