# PHP, AJAX, MYSQLI and IE9 not outputting as expected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am using a combination of PHP, AJAX, and MYSQLI to load suggestions of what a user is typing (fires off to load at each keypress). This is all working nicely in chrome, ie10, firefox, safari, etc. Then I tried it on IE9, and it just displayed "No Suggestions" (which I coded to do if it found no matches). My only thought was that it could be a caching issue that I read about on google, but on trying all the suggestions.. I ended up where I started.. "No Suggestions". So, I'm stumped. Here's the code for my AJAX:

```
function activelyLoad(passedInfo, insertInto, urlInLib)
{
    if (passedInfo.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById(insertInto).innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(insertInto).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../lib/"+urlInLib+"?q="+passedInfo,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here's one of the PHP files I'm loading in:

```
<?php
include('config.inc.php');
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
$full = $_GET['q'];
$fullAr = explode(" ", $full);
$count = count($fullAr);
$var = $fullAr[0];
$query = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE (StudentFirstName LIKE '%$var%' OR StudentPrefferedName LIKE '%$var%' OR StudentLastName LIKE '%$var%')";
$response = "";
if ($count >= 2) {
    $var2 = $fullAr[1];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo WHERE ((StudentFirstName LIKE '%$var%' OR StudentPrefferedName LIKE '%$var%') AND StudentLastName LIKE '%$var2%') OR ((StudentFirstName LIKE '%$var2%' OR StudentPrefferedName LIKE '%$var2%') AND StudentLastName LIKE '%$var%')";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num_results > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['StudentID'];
    $functionList = "\"activelyLoad($id, 'detDiv', 'addtable.php'),showElem('#details')\"";
    $functionList2 = "\"logLoad($id),  showElem('#contactDets')\"";
    if(strcmp($row['StudentPrefferedName'], '') != 0){
    $response .= ("<tr><td>" . $row['StudentFirstName'] . " \"" . $row['StudentPrefferedName'] . "\" " . $row['StudentLastName'] . "</td><td><button type='button' onmousedown=" . $functionList . " onclick=" . $functionList2 . ">Get details</button></td></tr>");
    }
    else{
        $response .= ("<tr><td>" . $row['StudentFirstName'] . " " . $row['StudentLastName'] . "</td><td><button type='button' onmousedown=" . $functionList . " onclick=" . $functionList2 . ">Get details</button></td></tr>");
    }
}
}
else $response = "No suggestions";
echo($response);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Here is the relevant HTML output of this page in IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV=”Pragma” CONTENT=”no-cache”>
<title>XXXXXXX</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/searchScripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>XXXXXXXX</h1>

<p>Please select one of the following options:</p>
<ul>
<li><a id="searchLink" href="#" onclick="showElem('#search')">Search for a student</a></li>

<div id="search">
<p><b>To find a student, start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
Student Name: <input type="text" onkeyup="activelyLoad(this.value, 'txtHint', 'gethint.php'), showElem('#suggestions')">
</form>
<div id="suggestions"><h2>Suggestions:</h2> <div id="suggestionsBox"><table id="txtHint"><tr><td>No Suggestions</td></tr></table></div></div>
```

The only thing that makes me think it has to be a cache issue is that this WORKS on all modern up to date browsers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** IE9's console returns

```
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation. for 'document.getElementById(insertInto).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;'
```

Is this my issue? How is it invalid? How is the browser able to get to the AJAX to load the "No Suggestions" if it errors out here?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes in your code... Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: post your generated html. cross browser problems aways be html problem.

Comment: Is `$id` a number? IE9 might not like numeric IDs, since they're not allowed in HTML4.

Comment: if you have jQuery (as you've tagged the question) then **please** use the built in $.AJAX methods instead of attempting to roll your own.

Comment: Well, what does the browser console say in IE9? What js errors does it show up?

Comment: @MarcB several layers of security before this page. If the student workers using this know what mysql is i'll eat my hat.

Comment: you're directly taking query parameters and inserting them into queries. even a single `'` will kill your queries, e.g. consider a student whose name is `Miles O'Brien`. just because the injected value isn't malicious doesn't mean it can't break things.

Comment: @Barmar $id is indeed a number. what would be a good fix for this?

Comment: @MarcB I use addslashes before adding users into the database *EDIT mistyped. meant add.

Comment: @arkascha spits out a few errors about me using googlefonts because its a secure page.  I also have just noticed a SCRIPT600: INVALID target element for this operation at line 21 (document.getElementById(insertInto).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText)

Comment: removeslashes and addslashes are to sql injection protection as a piece of toilet paper is to soaking up a flash flood: **UTTERLY** useless.

Comment: @Guerra I will add that

Comment: @scunliffe are there direct benefits besides readability to this?

Comment: Ah, so the IE9 browser actually tells you what is wrong...

Comment: My earlier question was a mistake, I thought `passedInfo` was being used with `getElementById`. If the student ID isn't being used as an HTML `id=` value, it's not a problem.

Comment: Where is `detDiv` in the HTML?

Comment: @arkascha I actually don't understand what that error means / how that would be invalid

Comment: @Barmar this is just a portion of the page. detDiv is a second div later on in the page that will load details associated with the students. However, since I cant get the list of students to load, I haven't included that as I didn't think it was going to be relevant. That line is just passing those values to the function that will be called when that button is clicked.

Comment: Sounds to me like the selection in that line produces an empty set. The browser fails to access the attribute `innerHTML` of that.

Comment: @arkascha `innerHTML` is being applied to `getElementByID(insertInto)`, not the returned data.

Comment: @arkascha I don't understand how that could be the case. The table with the id that I am passing it exists (and is found in other browsers) before the ajax is called. it is set to display:none, but it then displays onkeyup. Should i have it display onkeydown?

Comment: Search for your error message and you'll find the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771498/error-on-ie-9-script600-invalid-target-element-for-this-operation

Comment: @Barmar I see. the issue is a table.. Great. thank you!

Comment: Now do you understand why you should have posted the HTML of `detDiv`?

Comment: @Barmar not particularly, since detDev didn't have a table in it, and couldn't be generated since it is generated based on a button generated in the gethint.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among many other issues you are trying to dump the AJAX results into a `<table>` element as the `.innerHTML` property.

*Internet Explorer* has a **bug** that won't let you set the content of a `table` tag via `.innerHTML` until the bug is fixed in **IE10**

Bug report: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/12/bug-210-no-innerhtml-support-on-tables.html

You would be better off to create a `<div>` and set the `.innerHTML` of that instead.

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and used the JQuery POST method and was able to continue using my table setup which had design advantages for me.